# Homework Question: Integral Limit change and Substitutions on Simple Physics Integral

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, mathematical-physics

[image]

Stuck on this problem. I don't know how they got the substitution for $x = r tan(\theta)$. I know they take the derivative for $x = r tan(\theta)$, but I am not understanding what they took the derivative respect to; changing from $dx \rightarrow d\theta$ for the substitution.

Also, the limits on integration. When I tried to change the limits from $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}$ to $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ I get it diverges. Some clarity in how my math is wrong would be awesome!

Comment: It would be illuminating for you to figure out the formula for $s$ in terms of the other variables in the triangle to see where the tangent substitution naturally comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the triangle formed by $s,r$ and $x$ there are the relations
$$s=\frac {r}{cos\theta}$$
$$x=r\tan\theta$$
being $r$ a constant.

When $\theta$ changes so does $x$. So, $dx=r·d(tan\theta)= \frac {r}{cos^2\theta}d\theta$

Substitute in the integral:
$$E_y= \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} k \frac {\lambda dx}{s^2} cos \theta \;=\; \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} k\lambda \frac {r·d\theta}{cos^2\theta}·\frac{cos^2\theta}{r^2}·cos\theta \;=\; \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} \frac {k\lambda}{r} cos\theta \;d\theta$$

For the limits of integration, notice that $x=-\infty$ when $\tan\theta=-\infty$ which means $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}$ The same way, for $x=\infty$ we get $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Taking the constants out of the integral and replacing the limits we reach to
$$E_y= \int_{x=-\infty}^{x=\infty} k \frac {\lambda dx}{s^2} cos \theta  \;=\; \frac {k\lambda}{r} \int_{\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}} cos\theta \;d\theta$$

Comment: I guess the only thing I would be stuck on is why when you take the derivative of $x = rtan(\theta)$ why does r stay. I thought when you take a derivative of a constant it goes away.

Comment: Or is this saying that the smallest changes in $x$ also change $d\theta$ so that is why?

Comment: @MD_ The derivative of a constant is zero when that constant is adding, but not when it's multiplying. And you may remenber $(a·b)'= a'·b+a·b'$ and apply to $r·tan\theta$

Comment: @MD_ $x$ and $\theta$ are related (the triangle) by the formula I posted. So you can take derivatives on both sides of that formula to get the relation between $dx$ and $d\theta$